# "The boys watched the fire grow bigger and bigger."

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

> The boys watched the fire grow bigger and bigger.

Why is 'watched' in past tense but grow in present tense?

Answer (score 1):

'Grow' is not used here as the present tense, rather it is the [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/). This is used after a verb of perception such as watch, see, hear, feel, notice, etc, (also make and let) and an object. We saw the ship sink, they watched the fire grow, I heard Peter speak, you will feel the phone vibrate, she let the fire burn, let's make the people laugh!

[see / hear + object + verb form](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv214.shtml#:%7E:text=Both%20see%20and%20hear%2C%20and,the%20door%20and%20come%20in.)